# I am trying to build a receipt application with javafx....how do i get a label object to be added up to an integer table field on button click

Tags: java, javafx

```
  //this is the button that add objects to the table cells

@FXML
private void OK01(ActionEvent event) 
{
 rImg20.setVisible(false);
 tv.setVisible(true);


 String combo022 = combo02.getValue().toString();
 Integer result = Integer.valueOf(prCombo01.getText());
 del01.setVisible(true);

 data.add(new InvoiceEntry(
 (String) combo01.getValue(),
 combo022,   
 (String) combo03.getValue(),
 (String) combo04.getValue(),

 (Integer)prCombo01.getText()));       //but i cant get this label to add to the    
                                                                 integer column (price) of the table 
}
```

I ve written every code that is supposed to make this happen like...The InvoiceEntry.java and its .fxml. Please guys help me out here "please how do I get about this issue". I can show you the other codes if you want as i dont know how i can post all at once here with stack exchange

This is the completion of the code.

InvoiceEntry.java

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;

public class InvoiceEntry 
{
private final SimpleStringProperty clothe;
private final SimpleStringProperty pattern;
private final SimpleStringProperty designer;
private final SimpleStringProperty color;
private final SimpleIntegerProperty price;


public InvoiceEntry(
String clothe,
String pattern,
String designer,
String color,
Integer price
) 

{
this.clothe = new SimpleStringProperty( clothe );
this.pattern = new SimpleStringProperty( pattern);
this.designer = new SimpleStringProperty( designer );
this.color = new SimpleStringProperty( color );
this.price = new SimpleIntegerProperty( price );
}

public String getClothe() 
{
return clothe.get();
}

public void setClothe(String iName) 
{
this.clothe.set( iName );
}

public String getPattern() 
{
return pattern.get();
}

public void setPattern(String iName) 
{
this.pattern.set( iName );
}


public String getDesigner() 
{
return designer.get();
}

public void setDesigner(String iName) 
{
this.designer.set( iName );
}

public String getColor() 
{
return color.get();
}

public void setColor(String iName) 
{
this.color.set( iName );
}

public Integer getPrice() 
{
return price.get();
}

public void setPrice(Integer iName) 
{
this.price.set( iName );
}
}
```

FXML

```
@FXML
private TableView tv;
@FXML
private TableColumn<InvoiceEntry, String> clothe;
@FXML
private TableColumn<InvoiceEntry, String> pattern;
@FXML
private TableColumn<InvoiceEntry, String> designer;
@FXML
private TableColumn<InvoiceEntry, String> color;
@FXML
private TableColumn<InvoiceEntry, Integer> price;
@FXML
private ComboBox combo01;
@FXML
private ColorPicker combo02;
@FXML
private ComboBox combo03;
@FXML
private ComboBox combo04;
@FXML
private Label prCombo01;

private ObservableList<InvoiceEntry> data;



@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
    clothe.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, String>("clothe") );

    pattern.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, String>("pattern") );

    designer.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, String>("designer") );

    color.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, String>("color") );

    price.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, Integer>("price") );



    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    new InvoiceEntry("", "", "", "", 0));
    tv.setItems(data);
}



//this is the button that adds objects to the table cells
@FXML
private void OK01(ActionEvent event) 
{
     rImg20.setVisible(false);
     tv.setVisible(true);


      String combo022 = combo02.getValue().toString();
      Integer result = Integer.valueOf(prCombo01.getText());
      del01.setVisible(true);

      data.add(new InvoiceEntry(
                    (String) combo01.getValue(),
                     combo022,   
                    (String) combo03.getValue(),
                    (String) combo04.getValue(),

                    (Integer)prCombo01.getText()));//but i cant get this label to add to the 
                                                                              integer column (price) of the table 


}
```

Comment: you need to show us how you are declaring the table. The code is not enough.

Comment: I want a label whose integer value adds up to the table on a click of a button

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly typed language and you can't just cast `String` to `Integer` but you can user [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) however you should be ready that parse might fall with a `NumberFormatException` if string is not actually and integer number.

And one more thing, "price" is probably not and `int`/`Integer`, most probably you want to use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead (but, please, please, never use `double`/`Double` or `float`/`Float` for anything related to money!). `BigDecimal` might be created from a `String` using [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String))